# Show resolved APT package dependency tree

Tags: apt, dpkg, dependencies

Is there a way to print out a dependency tree (recursive) for a given APT package, that would contain a full version of each dependency that was resolved (installed)?

For example with `apt-rdepends`:

```
$ apt-rdepends --state-follow=Installed libssl1.1

libssl1.1
  Depends: debconf (>= 0.5)
  Depends: debconf-2.0
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17)
debconf
  PreDepends: perl-base (>= 5.20.1-3~)
...
```

I'd like to get information about which version of `debconf` it's resolved to on this machine.

If I do:

```
$ apt show debconf

Package: debconf
Version: 1.5.73
...
```

I see that it's `debconf` version `1.5.73`, so is there any tool that will print out the full package dependency tree with resolved dependency versions?

Thank you!

Comment: A "full" tree may run to thousands of items, nearly all of which will have versions that simply match your release of Ubuntu. The whole point of "apt" for the past 24 years is to avoid such manual tracking of dependencies and versions. What is the problem that such a dependency tree is intended to solve?

Comment: I understand your point and it makes sense to me. The problem I'm trying to solve is that I need to prove that certain packages that my package depends on are fips compliant (like: "openssl 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.fips.2.8"). So instead of just seeing that it's a openssl dependency, I'd like to see its version on the given machine. Does it make sense?